# How to change color of tabbar of neovim

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, highlight

How can I change the color of tabbar background (which is green in below screenshot)

[image]

Comment: I think this uses the current airline theme. Check the output of `hi airline_tabfill`. This most likely comes from not properly configured terminals. Might also be a airline theme issue (check your theme: `:echo g:airline#themes#<name>#palette['normal']` and replace <name> by whatever name your currently using, looks like you are using the `dark` theme there.)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!